# JQuery or JavaScript Replace Text w/ img background on Page Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, replace

I've been trying to change the text that's within the #vehicle .partnumber section on the page from Click For More Info to Click Here For Price, preferably with a background image.

[Website here.](http://clutchflywheel.com/store/product/itmgroupdetail.aspx?GroupId=60860&Make=EAGLE)

I tried JQuery replace as well as the java-script and gotten as far as appending text before and after, also replacing the section with an image - but then the link did not work.

Any recommendations or solutions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#vehicles .partnumber a').html('Click Here For Price');
```

for text replacement
Try

```
$('#vehicles .partnumber a').html('<img src="<YOUR_IMAGE_URL>" border=0/>');
```

for image replacement.

Comment: Cybernate, thank you for your response;

I appended the following text:
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#vehicles .partnumber a').html('Click Here For Price');
</script>

No changes have taken place. Can you visit the url and see if there's anything else that is preventing the text from updating?

Thank you!

Comment: You shuold call the javascript function ocne the dom s ready and the elements are created. Try this $(document).ready
(
 function()
 {
  $('#vehicles .partnumber a').html('Click Here For Price'); 
 }
)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if i understood it correctly, but this changes the link text and sets a backround image:

```
$('#vehicle .partnumber a).html('Click Here For Price').css('background-image','url(someimage.jpg)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$("#vehicle .partnumber").each(function(index, el)){

   // change the background of the td element
   $(el).css("background-image","url(/myimage.jpg)");

   // Remove the text from the inner anchor tag
   $(el).find("a").html("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
$('#vehicle .partnumber a).html('Click Here For Price').append('<img src="path/to/img"/>');
```